# Removing part of a string inside a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in my Data frame which looks like so:

Input

`df['location.display_name']`

Output

```
 Kelso, Scottish Borders
 Manchester, Greater Manchester
 Northampton, Northamptonshire
 Reading, Berkshire
 Leicester, Leicestershire
 Newport, Wales
 Swindon, Wiltshire
 Perth, Perth & Kinross
 Manchester, Greater Manchester
 Perth, Perth & Kinross
 Cardiff
 Hull, East Riding Of Yorkshire
 Chester, Cheshire
 Southampton
 Leamington Spa, Warwickshire
 Swindon, Wiltshire
 Slough, Berkshire
 Portsmouth, Hampshire
```

I want to create a new column with only the first part of the location - for example: Swindon, Wiltshire I'd like to keep Swindon and add that to a new column.

Also how will that affect some of the ones that I would like to keep are only one word like `Cardiff`?

Comment: Use `df['location.display_name'].str.split(',').str[0]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe need [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with select first `list`s by `str[0]` or select first column by `[0]`:

```
df['new'] = df['location.display_name'].str.split(',').str[0]
#alternative
#df['new'] = df['location.display_name'].str.split(',', expand=True)[0]
print (df)
              location.display_name              new
0           Kelso, Scottish Borders            Kelso
1    Manchester, Greater Manchester       Manchester
2     Northampton, Northamptonshire      Northampton
3                Reading, Berkshire          Reading
4         Leicester, Leicestershire        Leicester
5                    Newport, Wales          Newport
6                Swindon, Wiltshire          Swindon
7            Perth, Perth & Kinross            Perth
8    Manchester, Greater Manchester       Manchester
9            Perth, Perth & Kinross            Perth
10                          Cardiff          Cardiff
11   Hull, East Riding Of Yorkshire             Hull
12                Chester, Cheshire          Chester
13                      Southampton      Southampton
14     Leamington Spa, Warwickshire   Leamington Spa
15               Swindon, Wiltshire          Swindon
16                Slough, Berkshire           Slough
17            Portsmouth, Hampshire       Portsmouth
```

If not `NaN`s and `None`s in data is possible use `list comprehension`:

```
df['new'] = [x.split(',')[0] for x in df['location.display_name']]
```

Answer (score 1):

For executing a custom functionality on each element of you column you can use the pandas `apply` function. In your case the following code should do the job:

```
import pandas
import numpy

def get_first_substring(x):
    if (x!=None and x!=numpy.nan):
        return x.split(',')[0]

dataframe['new'] = dataframe['location.display_name'].apply(get_first_substring)
```

The output will look like:

```
          old                     new
subsstring1, subsstring2      subsstring1
```

Comment: There is only problem if `None` or `NaN`s, then it failed. The best is `df['new'] = df['location.display_name'].str.split(',').str[0]`

Comment: I edited the solution to check for `None` and `nan`.